# In Python, is there a way to tell a type checker that a value for a field will only be assigned after a function is called?

Tags: python, api, class, asynchronous, websocket

I'd like to be able to set a class field to None upon initialization and say that it will be not None after some other function/method is called. I'd like to do this because I'm writing an API wrapper that can only assign certain values after certain other data has been sent.

Here's an extremely rudimentary example to illustrate what I mean. The code below defines a class that only instantiates a websocket connection (using the websockets library) after the `connect` function has been called, after which it's used freely by other (undefined in this class) methods. The connection can't be made during the class's initialization, because `client.connect` is an async function.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import asyncio
from websockets import client

@dataclass
class Client:
    token: str
    intents: int

    # Here is where I would like a decorator or something
    #  to note that the Client.websocket field will be
    #  defined after Client.connect is called.
    websocket: client.WebSocketClientProtocol = None
    # I'm interfacing with the Discord API, but the main
    #  idea is that upon connecting / something happening
    #  this gateway sends data, and can be sent data in
    #  response.
    uri = "wss://gateway.discord.gg"

    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.connect())
        loop.run_until_complete(self.main())

    async def connect(self):
        self.websocket = await client.connect(self.uri)

    # Here, there might need to be some sort of
    #  @after(connect) decorator, to denote that this
    #  is only called after Client.connect has been
    #  called.
    async def main(self):
        while True:
            data = await self.websocket.recv()

            # Here is where we handle / send data
            #  through the websocket via other async
            #  methods.

client = Client("secret token", 0)

client.start()
```

This is close to the problem I'd like to solve, where the instance is sort of building itself as it goes and doesn't have access to the data it needs when it starts up.

For further example, the instance receives data defining a heartbeat interval immediately after the connection is made, and the `main` method would recieve it and give it to another method that assigns the heartbeat interval to the class instance.

I'm struggling because I don't know exactly how to word this question in a way that's concise enough for a search to give me something helpful. I'm open to any libraries or frameworks or even straight-up different design paradigms that will allow me and a type checker to know at which point things are being run and at which point things have been assigned.

Comment: What do you mean by "say that it will be not None after some other function/method is called"? How are other users of `Client` going to make use of that information? Do you want the other clients to wait until the field is not `None`?

Comment: @Mr.Fegur Apologies if the example is misleading. There are no other users of `Client`; it's meant to be an example of how I would interface with a websocket. The inner workings aren't important. I'm looking to be able to define for myself and a type checker that a value will be assigned after a certain function has been called.

Comment: Can you give it type Optional[TypeItWillBe] and a docstring for human user?

Comment: @Mr.Fegur That's what I've been resorting to, but the type checker (I'm using Pylance) doesn't like it, and will whine at me when I try to use the field's methods since it doesn't know that the field is not None. I've also considered putting an `assert`ion up top of all of the methods that will be called once the field has been assigned, but that feels like brute-forcing the type checker into submission (which might end up as what I do anyway, but I'd like a more elegant solution if one exists).